# GCP no resources available in asia-south1-c since a month

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create a VM on GCP since last month, but have not been able to do so.

I'm getting below error-

The zone 'projects/xxxxxxxxxxx/zones/asia-south1-c' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

Answer (score 1):

At first, there's no error on your side. Situation like this happened from time to time and usually it didn't take as long to add resources to zone and fix it.

In case you need resources urgently you can use different zone if you're able.

**EDIT** `ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED` error means that you are encountered with the temporary resource stock-out issue at that particular zone. Have a look at this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gce-discussion/asJA71NDkZM/2qon8TQZBQAJ) by *Paul Nash*, who explained the resource stock-out issue at Google Cloud Platform.

**The recommended workaround is to try a different zone** or check that particular zone later.

I'd recommend you to follow this steps, if you need to request resources for that specific zone/region:

1. open a ticket at [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187134&template=1162877) (more information [here](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker))
2. contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) (via email if you don't have a support contract)

**Confirmation of the issue**: You can check if you have `ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED` error at `Stackdriver` -> `Logging` -> `Logs Viewer` by using this query:

```
resource.type="gce_instance"
"ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED"
```

more information how to use Advanced logs queries you can find in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries).

**EDIT2** More information about this issue you can find in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#vm-not-created):

> If you receive a resource error (such as ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED
> or ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS) when requesting new
> resources, it means that the zone cannot currently accommodate your
> request.

and possible solutions:

> - Because this situation is temporary and can change frequently based on fluctuating demand, try your request again later.
> - If possible, try to create the resources in another zone in the region or in another region.
> - If possible, change the shape of the VM you are requesting. It's easier to get smaller machine types than larger ones. A change to your
>   request, such as reducing the number of GPUs or using a custom VM with
>   less memory or vCPUs, might allow your request to proceed.
> - Use [Compute Engine reservations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) to reserve resources within a zone to ensure that the resources you need are available when you need them.
> - If you are trying to create a preemptible instance, remember that preemptible VMs are spare capacity and so might not be obtainable at
>   peak demand periods.
> - If you receive a `notFound` or `does not exist` in zone error when requesting new resources, it means that the zone does not offer the
>   resource or machine type that you have requested. See [Regions and
>   zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/) to find out which features are available in each zone.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "The zone 'projects/[...]' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later." is always in reference to a shortage of resources in a zone.

As mentioned by @Serhii Rohoza, We recommend deploying and balancing your workload across multiple zones or regions to reduce the likelihood of an outage. In this type of situation the best workaround is to create your instance in a different zone or try later. To create your instance in another zone you will need to create a snapshot first, then create a new instance using the snapshot you have created.

**Steps :**

1. Go to compute engine and create a snapshot of Instance
2. Create a new instance with your created snapshot.
3. Choose the snapshot and create the instance in a different zone
4. Now we need to move our disk to a separate region. Check your previous zone name and disk name. To do that click on the instance name and scroll down to see the disk name.
5. Detach the boot disk from the previous instance. To do that edit the instance and click on the x icon to detach the disk.
6. Move that disk to different region. Run the following command to move disk to different region

   ```
    $ gcloud compute disks move <disk-name> --zone=<source-zone>  --destination-zone=<destination-zone>
   ```
7. Now stop the newly created machine. Edit the new machine and go to the boot disk, detach the previously created Disk.
8. Add the old disk as a boot disk.
9. Start the server.
10. Now you have to assign the previously created static Ip to the new machine. Go to Ip settings inside the VPC network. Click on change and assign the IP to the new machine.

Refer [resource availability](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#resource_availability) for information about ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED.